# Why the strange limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When we take the limit, we get an `Interval`. Why? What does it say about the function? I know that when $0$ or $\pi$ are substituted we get exact values, otherwise we get complex numbers.

```
a = FindSequenceFunction[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15}, n]/n // FullSimplify
Table[a, {n, 1, 20}]
Limit[a, n -> Infinity]

(* ((-1)^n + (-1)^(2 n) (-1 + 6 n))/(4 n) *)

(* {1, 3/2, 4/3, 3/2, 7/5, 3/2, 10/7, 3/2, 13/9, 3/2, 16/11, 3/2, 
    19/13, 3/2, 22/15, 3/2, 25/17, 3/2, 28/19, 3/2} *)

(* 3/2 E^(2 I Interval[{0, \[Pi]}]) *)
```

Comment: It means that the function continues to oscillate indefinitely.

Comment: @Graumagier, make that an answer so I can sign off on it.

Comment: Xavier has gone through all the trouble of putting together a comprehensive answer, so he should get the honor ;)

Comment: @FredKline Thanks for the accept and the bounty!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Limit` does not make any assumption regarding the domain of definition of the function.

In your specific example, the function oscillates in $\mathbb{C}$ when `n` belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, which explains why you obtain an `Interval`.

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Re[a], {n, 1, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Real part"], 
             Plot[Im[a], {n, 1, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Imaginary part"]}]
```

[image]

```
Limit[ReIm[a], n -> Infinity]
(* {Interval[{-(3/2), 3/2}], Interval[{-(3/2), 3/2}]} *)
```

When `n` is in $\mathbb{N}$, you have a well-defined limit as you can see from the sequence given by `Table[a, {n, 1, 20}]`. This limit can be obtained by evaluating

```
Limit[a, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
(* 3/2 *)
```

Comment: Another useful plot: `ParametricPlot[ReIm[a], {n, 1, 10}]`. For *Mathematica* versions older than 10.1, `{Re[a], Im[a]}` should be used in place of `ReIm[a]`.